# Automatic {target=_blank} for all links

Tags: javascript, markdown, pelican

I have [found](http://mitchbarry.com/handling-external-links/) this script that can add the blank feature to each link in html.

```
(function() {
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var new_tab = true;
    var set_icon = true;
    for (var links = document.links, i = 0, a; a = links[i]; i++) {
        if (a.hostname !== hostname) {
            if (new_tab)
                a.target = '_blank';
            if (set_icon)
                a.innerHTML +=
                    '<i class="fa fa-external-link fa-1 external-link-margin" />';
        }
    }
})();
```

**Is there any way how I can make it work automatically on html generation form md files in Pelican static blog engine?** So that it is added to every html file and modifies the links.

Comment: Just put it in a script tag in your base template?

Comment: @jonrsharpe But after theme update from git repo it will be lost. I want to keep customisations out of theme files e.g. `static_files` of the `content` directory. Can this be done?

Comment: As ever, you can just put HTML within the markdown. You could also create your own theme, either forking an existing one or starting from scratch, which reduces your dependency on the author not making changes you disagree with.

Comment: `<base target="_blank">` in the `<head>` of the blog template?

Comment: [Just don't](https://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/). It's one of the most annoying things ever.

Answer (score 1):

I found a `Python-Markdown` extension [Phuker/markdown_link_attr_modifier](https://github.com/Phuker/markdown_link_attr_modifier) which does exactly what you want. In fact, it can be configured to add any attribute to generated `<a>` tags.

According to the readme, just run `pip` command to install it, and add it to `MARKDOWN` variable in the `pelicanconf.py` file as an extension. I tried in my Pelican blog, and it works good.